# Can I implement this code more simply (shorter) by groovy?

Tags: gradle, groovy

Can I implement this code more simply (shorter) by groovy?

```
task uninstall(type: Delete) {
    def dirToDelete = System.properties['....'] + File.separator + ... + "..."

    def paths = project.group.toString().split("\\.")

    for (def p : paths)
        dirToDelete = dirToDelete + File.separator + p

    dirToDelete = dirToDelete + ...
    somethingDid(dirToDelete)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the repetitive `File.separator` by collecting all the path elements into a list and joining them on the separator:

```
task uninstall(type: Delete) {
    def paths = [System.properties['....'], "..."]

    paths << project.group.split(/\./)

    paths << ...
    somethingDid paths.flatten().join(File.separator)
}
```

**Notes**:

- `toString()` is not needed when splitting `project.group` as it is already a string
- `split("\\.")` can be replace with slashy string, so the backslash does not need to be escaped: `split(/\./)`